# What are the idiomatic meaning(s) of "roll/rolling" as used in sea shanties?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

Having been caught up in the recent resurgence of interest in sea shanties, I've noticed frequent--and apparently idiomatic--usage of the verb "roll/rolling" in their lyrics.

It appears in such shanties as:

- Roll the Old Chariot *(title)*
- Rolling Down to Old Maui *(title)*
- Bound for South Australia *("heave away, you rolling king")*
- Sally Brown *("roll and go"; "And we rolled all night, And we rolled all day")*
- Where Am I To Go M'Johnnies *("high roll and go")*
- Randy-Dandy-O *("roll and go")*

Often, it appears to be synonymous with "sailing" or "travelling by ship". However, it seems possible that it also has some other idiomatic meaning, especially in the frequent phrase "roll and go".

**What are the meaning(s) of "roll/rolling" as used in sea shanties?**

Comment: I've always assumed that it refers to the "rolling" of the waves.

Comment: I had the same initial intuition, and I think that would be a very sensible explanation for the origin of "rolling" as a synonym for sailing. Like, "Rolling (over the waves) down to old Maui". :)

Comment: "Roll the Old Chariot (Along)" or "A Drop of Nelson's Blood" is a bit different from most of the others as it refers to the purpose of the song which was used as both a pump shanty and a rowing shanty. In both cases repetitive "rolling" motions of the body and arms were necessary to fulfil the task. In the case of pumping the handles of the pump were mounted on large wheels and the action was rotary rather than up and down. If the ship had sprung a leak it was necessary to pump more or less continuously just to keep her afloat. A hard and tedious job, watch after watch.

Answer (score 2):

It describes the motion of a ship:

From the OED:

> **roll, v.2**
>
> **I. To move with a swaying motion, and related senses.
> **
> **1.a. intransitive. Of a vessel: to sway; esp. to rock, often violently, from side to side.**
>
> a1325   Pilate (Corpus Cambr.) l. 253 in C. D'Evelyn & A. J. Mill S. Eng. Legendary (1956) 706 (MED)   *Þat body [sc. a ship] rollede vp & doun, icast here & þere Myd weder & tempest of watere, þat echmon hadde fere. [That object (i.e. a ship] rolled up and down thrown hither and thither ...]*
>
> 2000   M. Kneale Eng. Passengers (2001) xiv. 428   *I could feel the whole vessel rolling sharp to larboard, as if some great hand was tugging her over.*
>
> **1.b. intransitive. Of a vessel: to move along with a swaying motion.In some quots. (esp. in later use) the sense of a swaying motion is less marked, perhaps representing an extended use**.
>
> 1740   H. Travers tr. Homer Iliad ii. in Misc. Poems & Transl. 255   *When wint'ry Winds the Face of Ocean sweep, And the Ship rolls along the stormy Deep.*
>
> 2002   C. Loebel-Fried Hawaiian Legends of Guardian Spirits iii. 37   *Powered by wind, the vessel rolled on toward Hawai'i,..plowing through the dark sea beneath a blue-black sky.*

Comment: It does mean that, of course, but there is also the implied double meaning of "rolling in bed" and "rolling in her arms" in many shanties. The lads might have been out at sea for months but part of their minds was always on the shore!